# Scala - Pattern matching on arrays doesn't warn for missing cases

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

It appears that the pattern matcher for Arrays doesn't complain for missing cases.
For example, if I try to read from the `args` Array of String...

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val limit = args match {
    case Array(x, _*) => { println("Running for " + x) ; x.toInt }
    // case _ => 1000
  }
}
```

...the compiler is silent even though I didn't match all possible Array cases (e.g. the empty one). But if I convert the array to List...

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val limit = args.toList match {
    case x :: xs => { println("Running for " + x) ; x.toInt }
    // case _ => 1000
  }
}
```

...then the compiler catches the error, and reports:

```
[warn] missedErrorCase.scala:38: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Nil
[warn]     val limit = args.toList match {
[warn]                      ^
[warn] one warning found
```

Have I missed something, or is this a bug in the pattern matching logic of Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be impossible for the compiler to know that the match is not exhaustive without special-casing `Array` in some way. `unapplySeq` is too general.

Consider the (not far-fetched) example of a "non-empty sequence" type.

```
class NonEmptySeq[A](val head: A, val tail: Seq[A]) {
  def toIndexedSeq: IndexedSeq[A] = head +: tail.toIndexedSeq
}

object NonEmptySeq {
  def unapplySeq[A](x: NonEmptySeq[A]): Option[IndexedSeq[A]] =
    Some(x.toIndexedSeq)
}

def limit(args: NonEmptySeq[String]) =
  args match { case NonEmptySeq(x, _*) => x.toInt }
```

The match in this case is exhaustive because unapplying a `NonEmptySeq` will always produce at least one value, but the compiler can't see that.

Note that if you simply replace `Array` with `List`, you have the same problem. This code doesn't produce any warning either:

```
def limit(args: List[String]) =
  args match { case List(x, _*) => x.toInt }
```

The match expression `x :: xs` is sugar for `::(x, xs)`. The `::` class seems unfortunately omitted from the scaladoc, so I'll have to encourage you to look at [the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1). The class definition looks something like this (I've fictionalized it here for the sake of simplicity):

```
case class ::[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

The match expression `x :: xs` refers to the `::.unapply` method that is generated automatically because `::` is a case class.

The compiler knows that there are two subtypes of `List` (and that there are exactly two, because `List` is sealed):

- `::`
- `Nil`

So when you have

```
def limit(args: List[String]) =
  args match { case x :: xs => x.toInt }
```

`::` is covered by the pattern match, but `Nil` isn't - hence the warning.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and detailed answer. If I understand you correctly, this means that there's no way for compile-time exhaustive checking of Array pattern matches, since for Arrays there are no sealed case subclasses (like the '::','Nil' for List).

Comment: @ttsiodras But Array *is* final, which is stronger than sealed, so I think that's a misleading way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

List is a `sealed abstract class` in scala. If you use `.toSeq` instead `.toList`, you will not get warning, because Seq is just `trait`. Scala uses this sealed keyword to check whether the match statements are exhaustive.